# CosmosDB Asynch client : Iterator<FeedResponse<Document>> it is getting stuck on hasNext() method

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Following code where I'm trying to run cross partition query is getting stuck on it.hasNext() line. Not able to debug further here :

```
    public List<MyDataObject> getList() {
    List<Document> documentList =null;
    List<MyDataObject> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
        feedOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);
        SqlQuerySpec querySpec = null;
        querySpec = new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT * FROM MyDataObjectColl");
        Iterator<FeedResponse<Document>> getDataFromCosmos = myDocumentClient.queryDocuments(collectionLink, querySpec, feedOptions).toBlocking().getIterator();
        while (getDataFromCosmos.hasNext()) { //GETTING STUCK ON THIS LINE FOR SOME REASON
            FeedResponse<Document> page = getDataFromCosmos.next();
            System.out.println("Request Unit Cost for getList " + page.getRequestCharge());
            documentList = page.getResults();
            for (Document doc : documentList) {
                if (doc != null) {
                    returnList.add(gson.fromJson(doc.toJson(), MyDataObject.class));
                }
            }
        }
    }   catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

SDK version :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hey, CosmosDB internal expert please point out what could have caused this behavior I'm suspecting some library is missing which is getting blocking, please help.

Comment: Can you add which SDK version are you using?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta version updated in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected there was version issue which was causing this, basically my application internal library was using following version of **commons-lang3** :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But **azure-cosmosdb 2.4.4** requires different :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Detail explanation:**
Basically cosmosdb internally in class *FetchExecutionRangeAccumulator* uses a line `this.stopwatch.getTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` but `long getTime(final TimeUnit timeUnit)` is present in 3.8.1 version of commons-lang3 not in 3.3.1 due to which it was internally getting stuck at polling code and was intermittently throwing exception (method not found in commons-lang3) if retry same code flow.